# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire Reason: image not found

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, alamofire

i am getting the above problem for long time. tried everything. 
i am using xcode 9.4 and alamofire is used inside a framework using cocopods and this framework is being used in a single application . when ever i run the app the app builds successfully and then the above error happens and app crashes.

Comment: did you delete any certificate from keychain ?

Comment: got the issue. cocopods does not allow integrating Pods into framework targets.

Comment: certificates in key chain is fine

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove Pods
2. Clean Derived Data
3. Reinstall Pods

this worked for me.

if this doesn't work try to delete .xcworkspace and reinstall pods

Comment: did it and its still the same. is there some thing i need to do in framework file or the app file.

Comment: are you using last version of Alamofire?
than try removing pods and re installing them
import in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries
Full clean and a build

If this doesn't work I dunno what it can be

Comment: yes using alamofire 4.7. did all the stuff you told but still the same issue. even my apple certificate is valid.

Comment: I don't know what's going on than, I'm sorry

Comment: got the issue. cocopods does not allow integrating Pods into framework targets.